# Identify the caller of method when 2 inputs call same method on change in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Lets say I have a table with 2 columns (userid, username). I have two input text fields which on change call a method say filter() to filter data displayed in a table. In AngularJS how would I identify which element called the filter() method. Also I would like to access the data attributes of the calling element as well. I am just starting with Angular and any help would be great !

My HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table><thead>
<tr><th><input type="text" class="filter" ng-model="jobid" ng-change="filter()" data-filterby="jobid"/></th>
<th><input type="text" class="filter" ng-model="name" ng-change="filter()" data-filterby="name"/></th></tr>
</thead></table>
</div>
```

My AngularJS Controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.filter = function() {
    $item = angular.element(this);
    $item.val();
    /* ^^ This doesnt work - Throws an error*/
  }
```

I know I can easily have separate function names for each text box, but I would like a common function to handle this to have a simpler code.
If it was jquery I could do something like this

```
$(".filter").keyup(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  var filterby = $(this).attr("data-filterby");
});
```

so which ever text box changes, i can get the value in that particular text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it doesn't appear that [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) supports `$event` like [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) does, you can either roll your own version of `ngChange` that exposes it or pass some indicator to your filter method like...

```
<input type="text" class="filter" ng-model="jobid" ng-change="filter('jobid')" data-filterby="jobid"/>
<input type="text" class="filter" ng-model="name" ng-change="filter('name')" data-filterby="name"/>
```

And then use it like:

```
$scope.filter = function(key) {
  console.log(key + ' is ' + $scope[key]);
}
```

I suppose I should ask... what are you trying to do with the value?  There is probably a more Angular way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to filter the values in the table based on what is entered in the input box.

Comment: Sounds like you just need `ngRepeat` w/ `filter`, no? http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/jPH74/

Comment: yes indeed. I am actually using ngRepeat but didnt think about filters.Do we have similar methods like this for sorting the data based on the values in the fields?

Comment: oh boy i have no idea how i missed those in the docs. Thanks a bunch !